# Returning into object from Assembly.LoadFrom() in C#

Tags: c#, dll

I'm trying to make an expansion setup for this game I'm developing, (not going to go into detail about), but all a single expansion will need is the 1 .dll file added into the `Expansions` folder I have added.

I have figured out how to access these .dll added into this folder as seen below:

```
Assembly ExpAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Expansions/Intrique.dll");
Type myType = ExpAssembly.GetTypes()[0];
```

Here is an example of the class I'm trying to load:

```
public class Expansion: MyGame.Expansion {
    public Expansion() {
         //Stuff
    }
    public string SomeMethod()
    {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

Calling the following code runs SomeMethod() just fine

```
MethodInfo Method = myType.GetMethod("SomeMethod");
object myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
MessageBox.Show(Method.Invoke(myInstance, null).ToString());
```

But what I want to do is be able to write `Expansion expObj;` and assign it by calling `new Expansion()` from this not-referenced .dll, but not in the library itself.

Comment: Like this? `Expansion expObj = (Expansion) myInstance;` @DanielA.White

Comment: yea - did you try that?

Comment: You can't use a dynamically loaded type statically. If you want to do this, reference the dll normally.

Comment: Can't use Intrique.Expansion because it would cause compiler error.  But you could use MyGame.Expansion since Intrique.Expansion derives from it.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I'm doing this because I want users to be able to make their own expansions as well. :/

Comment: Anyhow @DanielA.White told me. I should have know to cast the object into the Expansion object. lol Silly me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(For the purposes of this answer, I'm going to assume that your `Expansion` subclass is has a fully qualified name of `Intrique.Expansion`. I.e. the namespace is the same as the name of the DLL).

Because your main program does not reference Intrique.dll, the code in your main program cannot use the types in that DLL directly. That is, `Intrique.Expansion` is not a usable type in the context of the written code of your main program, though it can be used at run-time.

Taking your code example literally, the only approach likely to work given the code you have now would be to use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);

myInstance.SomeMethod();
```

This is because `SomeMethod()` is declared *only* in `Intrique.Expansion`. There's not any other type you could use statically in your main program where that method is known.

If that method was instead an implementation of a member of some interface that `Intrique.Expansion` implements and which your main program references, or was an `override` of some `virtual` member of `MyGame.Expansion` (which presumably your main program references, if not actually declares), then you could cast the instance to the interface type or `MyGame.Expansion` respectively and call the method that way:

```
ISomeInterface myInstance = (ISomeInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(myType);

myInstance.SomeMethod();
```

or:

```
MyGame.Expansion myInstance = (MyGame.Expansion)Activator.CreateInstance(myType);

myInstance.SomeMethod();
```

Finally, given that you are trying to implement some kind of extensibility architecture, you might consider using the [Managed Extensibility Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx), which is designed specifically to handle a lot of the messy parts of exactly this kind of thing.

Comment: What I ended up doing was `MyGame.Expansion expObj = (MyGame.Expansion) myInstance;` and it is working as I need it to.